# How do I make a "custom profile" where users can set their own status? discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a code for a "custom profile" where players can set what they wish, an image of an example of a bot would make more sense.

[image: 1]

Something like this. I'm not asking for an entire code, but just the basis of how do I start, I really don't understand how do I take a users input and then put it into a file. That's all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store data in a file, you can use the `json` library :

Your blank json file, which will contain every user's custom profile, would look like this :

```
[
     {'discord_id': 'id', 'name': 'test', 'desc': 'test'}
]
```

Once you've created your "blank" json file, here's the code to create, modify and delete profiles :

```py
from json import loads, dumps

def get_data():
    with open('members.json', 'r') as file:
    return loads(file.read())

def set_data(data):
    with open('members.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(dumps(data, indent=2))

def profile(name, desc, discord_id, mode):
    data = get_data()
    if mode == 'create':
        data.append({'discord_id': discord_id, 'name': name, 'desc': desc})
    elif mode == 'remove':
        for profile in data:
            if profile['discord_id'] == discord_id
                 del profile
    elif mode  == 'modify':
        for profile in data:
            if profile['discord_id'] == discord_id
                profile = {'discord_id': discord_id, 'name': name, 'desc': desc}
    set_data(data)
```

You can change the modify method, i wrote the simplest way to do it. You could have a separate function that handles profile modification, that would only change the specified argument.